# Ruby converting Array of Arrays into Array of Hashes

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

Please I need a help with this.

In Ruby If I have this array of arrays

```
array = [["a: 1", "b:2"],["a: 3", "b:4"]]
```

How can I obtain this array of hashes in ruby

```
aoh = [{:a => "1", :b => "2"},{:a => "3", :b => "4"}]
```

Comment: I tried to answer, but noticed the unusual syntax. Is the data being supplied to you that way, as a string-pair? Second question: Would splitting on a `:` be sufficient or is it possible the right-hand side may contain that character? Is the space optional, as one appears to be missing it.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". We appreciate that you might be new, but we do expect evidence of the effort you've put into this. Where did you search? Why didn't it help? If it did, where is the code you wrote to test what you learned? If you didn't write code, why not? If you did, what is the minimal code that demonstrates the problem you encountered, along with the explanation of the problem, and the minimal input data and the expected result? Without that it's hard to help you.

Comment: `[["a: 1", "b:2"],["a: 3", "b:4"]]` is not a normal definition of data, especially for an array of arrays of hashes. It looks suspiciously like an XY problem where you're asking about creating a hash but should have asked about how to gather the data prior to this step. "[What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/153968)"

Comment: It is an odd question, but it seems clear enough.

Comment: Yes, data is like String-Pair coming from a device output parsing result. Data source is random generating those spaces after the colon, Cary answer is the right one

Answer (score 3):

Note that, [like pointed out in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60048765/ruby-converting-array-of-arrays-into-array-of-hashes#comment106201624_60048765), this is most likely an XY-problem and instead of transforming the array the better option is to build the starting array in a better manner.

Nevertheless, you can do this in the following manner:

```
aoh = array.map { |array| array.to_h { |string| string.split(':').map(&:strip) } }
# => [{"a"=>"1", "b"=>"2"}, {"a"=>"3", "b"=>"4"}]
```

The above will give you string keys which is the safer option to go with. You can convert them to symbols, but they should [only be used for trusted identifiers](http://www.randomhacks.net.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/2007/01/20/13-ways-of-looking-at-a-ruby-symbol/#11). When the data comes from an user or external source I would go for the above.

Converting to symbols can be done by adding the following line:

```
# note that this line will mutate the aoh contents
aoh.each { |hash| hash.transform_keys!(&:to_sym) }
#=> [{:a=>"1", :b=>"2"}, {:a=>"3", :b=>"4"}]
```

Comment: My only suggestion is to use `split(/: */)` so you can ditch `.map(&:strip)`. Nice use of [Array#to_h](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-to_h) with a block, the optional block being new in v2.6.

Comment: Same comment as for Cary, in absence of assertion that there will only ever be one colon, a limit on `split` is a good idea.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I've thought about doing that, but `.map(&:strip)` will also remove whitespace in front of the key or after a value. This is in my opinion the safer way to go without knowing the allowed syntax of the string. However this might not be needed depending on the use-case and `.split(/: */)` may suffice.

Comment: Data source is random generating those spaces after the colon

Answer (score 1):

```
array = [["a: 1", "b:2"], ["a: 3", "b:4"]]
```

```
array.map do |a|
  Hash[
    *a.flat_map { |s| s.split(/: */) }.
       map { |s| s.match?(/\A\d+\z/) ? s : s.to_sym }
  ]
end
  #=> [{:a=>"1", :b=>"2"}, {:a=>"3", :b=>"4"}]
```

The regular expression `/: */` reads, "match a colon followed by zero or more (`*`) spaces". `/\A\d+\z/` reads, "match the beginning of the string (`\A`) followed by one or more (`+`) digits (`\d`), followed by the end of the string (`\z`).

The steps are as follows. The first is for the element `arr[0]` to be passed to the block, the block variable `a` assigned its value and the block calculation performed.

```
a = array[0]
  #=> ["a: 1", "b:2"]
b = a.flat_map { |s| s.split(/: */) }
  #=> ["a", "1", "b", "2"] 
c = b.map { |s| s.match?(/\A\d+\z/) ? s : s.to_sym } 
  #=> [:a, "1", :b, "2"]
d = Hash[*c]
  #=> {:a=>"1", :b=>"2"}
```

We see the array `["a: 1", "b:2"]` is mapped to `{:a=>"1", :b=>"2"}`. Next the element `arr[1]` is passed to the block, the block variable `a` is assigned its value and the block calculation is performed.

```
a = array[1]
  #=> ["a: 3", "b:4"] 
b = a.flat_map { |s| s.split(/: */) }
  #=> ["a", "3", "b", "4"] 
c = b.map { |s| s.match?(/\d/) ? s : s.to_sym } 
  #=> [:a, "3", :b, "4"] 
d = Hash[*c]
  #=> {:a=>"3", :b=>"4"}
```

The *splat* operator (`*`) causes `Hash[*c]` to be evaluated as:

```
Hash[:a, "3", :b, "4"]
```

See [Hash::[]](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D).

Comment: Why `Hash[]` in preference to `Array#to_h`?

Comment: It would be safer to do `.split(/: */, 2)`

Comment: @tadman, I prefer `to_h`, particular when used with a block, as 3limin4t0r has. I don't know why I went with `Hash::[]`. I now hate my answer, but will leave it for instructional reasons.

Comment: @Amadan, why safer? If one is worried that one of the strings might split into something other than two pieces, might it not be better to raise an exception if that were to happen (or am I missing your point)?

Comment: Depends what OP needs, as they haven't responded to @tadman's comment; but additional colons will break your code. Odd number of such elements will die with `ArgumentError (odd number of arguments for Hash`), and even will give unforeseen results; e.g. `[["name: Magic: the Gathering", "name: Vampire: the Masquerade"]]` results in `[{:name=>:Magic, :"the Gathering"=>:name, :Vampire=>:"the Masquerade"}]`, no error. Limiting the split makes it behave correctly. Raising an error when there is >2 splits is also an option. Silently ignoring it is not, unless the OP asserts only one colon per string.

Comment: I used `Hash[]` all the time before `.to_h` became reliably available, so maybe just first instinct?

Answer (score 0):

Loop through your items, loop through its items, create a new array:

```
array.map do |items| 
  items.map do |item| 
    k,v = item.split(":", 2)
    { k.to_sym => v } 
  } 
}
```

Note that we're using `map` instead of `each` which will return an array.